# CRecordset using 2 different queries

Tags: ms-access, mfc

I'm using CRecordset class to do data exchange between my class and Access database. This class is generated using ClassWizard in VC 6. CRecordset is opened using SQL SELECT * FROM Table query and it works fine. later in my code I have another method to find the number of records in the database. So using the same CRecordSet and using SQL SELECT count(*) FROM Table I get results sporadically and on error an unknown exception is thrown.

So, can a ClassWizard generated class of type CRecordset be used for different queries.